# Orders of elements of multiplicative group whose sum is $N$

Tags: group-theory

I found a problem regarding orders of elements in a group.

We have $S=\{1,2,...,N-1\}$. Let $G\subset S$ be a subset of $S$ that is a group under multiplication modulo $N$. Further, suppose $m,n\in G$ have orders $p$ and $q$, respectively.

Given that $m+n=N$, show that if $p,q$ are even then $p=q$.

I have so far done the following:
$m^p = (N-n)^p = n^p=e$, since using the Binomial Theorem, all terms except the term involving just $n$ are multiples of $N$, so all that is left is $(-1)^pn^p$, where $p$ is even. Then certainly  $n^p=e$, but how do I show that this is the minimal element?

Similarly another part of the problem is: if $p$ is even and $q$ is odd then $p=2q$. I believe we show that this works in a similar way to above, namely: $n^q = (N-m)^q = e \implies (-m)^q = e$. Thus $(-m)^q (-m)^q = e\implies m^{2q}=e$. But again how do I show that $2q$ is the least such element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part show similarly that $m^q=e$. Now you know that $q\mid p$ and $p\mid q$, so $p=q$.

For the second note that $n^p=(N-n)^p=m^p=e$, where the first equality follows from the fact that $p$ is even, so that $q\mid p$. On the other hand, your calculation shows that $p\mid 2q$, so $p\in\{q,2q\}$, and since $p\ne q$, we must have $p=2q$.

Comment: Thanks for this!

Comment: @Benjamin: My pleasure!